What are uvacahas in stotra chanting?
There are many stotras which have uvachas written in them . What are these uvachas and does one have to recite them to get any results?

Indra uvacha means Indra says .. many times a deity or Rishi is speaking the stotra then Uvacha will come in.

So do I have to recite it to get the fruits

Yes recite the whole stotra/kavacha without skipping anything

Ok thank you @Rickross.
